# Feature Upgrading - Adding an existing content type to a list definition

Tags: 2010, site-definition, feature-upgrade

My question is: how do I add an existing content type (say the OOTB "Contact" content type) to an list instance definition (for "Shared Documents") in my site definition solution?

Background: I have a solution (WSP) that originated from a "Save Site as Template" WSP. In it, there are several features that will provision list instances when the site is created. I have edited some of the definitions for the list instance (both manifest elements.xml and the schema.xml), and newly provisioned sites will have these "updates" - not a problem. 
However, I want to modify one of the document libraries, so that it has an additional content type, (say "Contact") - then with "feature upgrading", existing sites **and** newly created sites will have this new content type in that document library.

From a Feature Upgrading (ALM) perspective, how **should** this be done? I have been scouring sites and books for the answer to this question - and so far I haven't seen any direct answers to this...(although [this thread seems close](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/14910/upgrading-site-definition)) Many of the answers are about updating content types by adding fields.

I understand I can force this via OM (PowerShell), but I would like to leverage feature versioning for this. I think I'll need to do the bulk in code (programmatically) - but any guidance would be very helpful...

Answer (score 1):

Chris O'Brien has a good description of feature upgradeing in [Feature upgrade (part 1) - fundamentals](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2010/06/feature-upgrade-part-1-fundamentals.html).

To start off you need:

- Create the code to make the changes to the existing list (see [How to: Add a Content Type to a SharePoint List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa543576.aspx))
- Put that code inside `FeatureUpgrading` for your feature. It may be good to make the code generic and use an upgradeActionName like 'AddContentTypeToList' and pass the listname and content type id as parameters
- Add the `<CustomUpgradeAction>` element with right Name and Parameters inside `<UpgradeActions><<VersionRange>` for your feature
- Upgrade the solution (DON'T retract+deploy). To help when developing [CKSDEV](http://cksdev.codeplex.com/) adds an upgrade menuitem to visual studio (and a lot of other nice things)
- Upgrade the feature where needed ([Feature Upgrade Kit](http://spfeatureupgrade.codeplex.com/) may help here)

Comment: Yes, I've been going over both Chris O'Brien's articles and Jeremy Thake's video - but both didn't cover adding CT to list as an upgrade activity.
Anyhow, I've been ensuring I use Upgrade-SPSolution cmdlet instead of retract+deploy.